# GWT: [FATAL] Uncaught JavaScript exception [Script error.] in , line 0

Tags: debugging, gwt

I keep getting this error in web hosted mode GWT, but I'm not sure what's causing it. Is there a way to make it produce a more informative output? My approach right now is to step through line by line in the debugger until the problem appears, but it's a pain.

Comment: An uncaught JS exception should show up in the JS console - have you checked with Firebug?

Comment: I've checked with the chrome dev console, and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem went away when I disabled Chrome's Cortex extension. Odd.